# Trouble reading sheet music

Tags: theory, piano, sheet-music, self-learning

I've been learning a piece called "Recreation - The Swapper" by Carlo Castellano, and when it comes to these notes, I have no idea which notes I should play on my piano. Everything I try sounds just weird.

[image]

From what I've understood from my research, the symbol " ♮ " means that no matter what has been said, this cancels every particular thing about the note (sharps and flats).
It looks like I have to play G and Gsharp. May anyone confirm that, or tell me if I'm reading this sheet wrong?

*Sorry for my bad english :)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having no trouble reading.

In the video links below, Carlo Castellano is playing his own composition, the [sheet music](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wibjhyyahw0e5r/Carlo%20Castellano%20-%20Recreation.pdf?dl=0) of which appears in a link in the description to that video. (There is a [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/carlocastellano/06-recreation?in=carlocastellano/sets/the-swapper-soundtrack) link, as well.) A few sections are worth listening and viewing:

### 0:44–0:51, mm. 21–22.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/zgcX64aK3Vc?version=3&start=44&end=51

[image: Carlo Castellano, “Recreation,” mm. 21–22]

### 1:19–1:23, m. 37.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/zgcX64aK3Vc?version=3&start=79&end=83

[image: Carlo Castellano, “Recreation,” m. 37]

### 1:36–1:41, mm. 45–46.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/zgcX64aK3Vc?version=3&start=96&end=101

[image: Carlo Castellano, “Recreation,” mm. 45–46]

### 2:10–2:15, mm. 61–62.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/zgcX64aK3Vc?version=3&start=130&end=135

[image: Carlo Castellano, “Recreation,” mm. 61–62]

Castellano plays this pattern four times. Already, it becomes less likely that he has made the same transcription error this many times. It sounds somewhat strange, doesn’t it, G♯ and G♮ appearing in the same measure? Nonetheless, it is accurate. If you had any doubts about the sheet music, you can *see his fingers play it* in measure 37.

Answer (score 3):

I listened to the piece here:

Measures 21 and 22 definitely have some dissonance. I don't think there's any typo. The final two notes in the bass clef are G-natural and low G-sharp, as you suggest. It's supposed to sound dissonant. The trick is to play the phrase smoothly and with the same feeling as in previous measures.

Answer (score 3):

The second G# has a 'courtesy accidental', simply written in order to avoid any confusion (because of the previous G natural).

Comment: What 'previous G natural'? The only other one is in treble clef, so shouldn't be confused. An accidental *only* refers to the same pitch and name notes in the same octave as they are written. Unless you've seen a previous bar...

Comment: The note directly before the final G# in b. 21 is a G natural.  The natural symbol there is also a courtesy accidental.  It, like the following # symbol are only there for clarification.  The rule you mention about accidentals is understood, but sometimes composers prefer to err on the side of caution.

Answer (score -3):

If that bottom G was supposed to be G#, there would be no need to use another accidental - it's already sharp from the last one. Looks like a typo, and the sharp should be a natural. Giving two simple G naturals.

Comment: So why is there a sharp if it should be natural?

Comment: A typo is a mistake made when writing something out. I think that sharp *ought* to be a natural sign.

Comment: Both the natural sign and the second sharp sign are "courtesy" indications, just to reassure the performer that the dissonance was intended.